# Countdown timer dictated by MySQL data

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, countdowntimer

How do I go about using AJAX to create a dynamic countdown timer using MySQL and PHP?

Here is a scaled back version of my PHP script that interacts with my MySQL database, but how can I get it to countdown without having to refresh the page?

```
<?php
      $con = mysql_connect("database-server","username","password");

      mysql_select_db("database", $con);

      $sql = mysql_query("SELECT TIMEDIFF(example_finish, NOW()) FROM example;");

      echo "<table>
      <tr>
           <th>COUNTDOWN_TIMER</th>
      </tr>";

      while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      { 
           echo "<tr>";
           echo "<td>" . $row["TIMEDIFF(example_finish, NOW())"] . "</td>";
           echo "</tr>";
      }

      echo "</table>";

      mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: You'd have mysql return the timediff value as a plain integer - seconds remaining. That'd get passed on to the page and embedded in some javascript, which does the actual countdown stuff.

Comment: Thanks for that! :) Managed to figure it out - I was overcomplicating the problem.. *facepalm

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description I don't see you needing to poll the database other then to set up the initial countdown time.

I have found [this link to various implementations of countdown timers](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html).